# Redux Saga takeLatest doesn't cancel previous multiple request

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

just learn redux-saga today, what I read is that takelatest will cancel the same request and only execute the latest one, but my code seems didn't do that, everytime i click the fetch button it append a new request without cancel the previous one, hope someone can explain why, thanks.

[image: code]

[image: demo preview]

Answer (score 3):

It's going to cancel the *saga*, but that just means it won't resume the saga (other than going into a `finally` block, if any). If there's additional things you need to have it teardown, such as cancelling axios network requests, then you'll need to add the code for that yourself. For example:

```
function* getPeople() {
  const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
  try {
    const { data } = yield axios.request({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://localhost:3004/people',
      cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token
    });
    yield put(actions.setPeople(data));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(actions.setPeopleError({
      type: 'get_data',
      message: e.message
    });
  } finally {
    if (yield cancelled()) {
      cancelTokenSource.cancel();
    }
  }
}
```

There is another option too. When you yield a promise to redux-saga, if that promise has a special property on it, then redux-saga will call that property automatically when the saga is cancelled. So if you find yourself canceling axios network request often, you could set up a helper method which adds that property to your axios promises:

```
import { CANCEL } from 'redux-saga';

const req = () => {
  const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
  const promise = axios.request({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3004/people',
    cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token
  });
  promise[CANCEL] = () => cancelTokenSource.cancel();
  return promise;
}

function* getPeople() {
  try {
    const { data } = yield call(req);
    yield put(actions.setPeople(data));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(actions.setPeopleError({
      type: 'get_data',
      message: e.message
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, the first example worked, I was not able to get the second example to work I don't know the reason, there is no error.

Comment: Thanks for the working example, Nicholas. This is exactly I was looking for. Is there a way, where in multiple axios request are not sent in first place when there is already a request in flight ? Just want to avoid any cancellations. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh for that behavior i would typically use [takeLeading](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeleadingpattern-saga-args) instead of [takeLatest](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#takeleadingpattern-saga-args). takeLeading listens for an action, and then it will ignore all other of those actions until it's done working on the first one.